# A extends B; Type 'Pick<A, Exclude<keyof A, keyof B>> & B' is not assignable to type 'A'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

Is this the bug or do I misunderstand the typescript things?

Example code following:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

const func = <A extends B, B>() => {
  const aWithoutB: Omit<A, keyof B> = {} as any; // The {} assignment isn't important here.

  const b: B = {} as any;

  const a: A = {
    ...aWithoutB,
    ...b
  }; // warning here
};
```

IDE (VS Code) Warning with TypeScript 3.4.5:

```
Type 'Pick<A, Exclude<keyof A, keyof B>> & B' is not assignable to type 'A'.ts(2322)
```

I think the 2 types are equal but no. What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is that the compiler currently [doesn't perform](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) the kind of higher-order type analysis necessary for it to understand an equivalence between an unresolved generic object type and intersections of complementary sets of properties of that type.  It's not clear from the status of the linked issue whether such analysis will ever be implemented; it's no doubt possible to make the compiler account for such things, but who knows if it can be done without degrading compiler performance?

---

A secondary reason is that those two types are *not* actually equivalent.  Consider the following interfaces `Beta` and `Alpha`:

```
interface Beta {
    x: string | number,
    y: boolean,
    z?: object  
}

interface Alpha extends Beta {
    x: string,
    y: true,
    z: undefined
}

func<Alpha, Beta>(); // no error, but uh oh

declare const beta: Beta;
declare const alpha: Alpha;
const notAlpha: Alpha = { ...alpha, ...beta }; // error!
```

Note that `Alpha extends Beta`, but if you spread an `Alpha` followed by a `Beta` into a new object, you do *not* get an `Alpha`.  And so you can call `func<Alpha, Beta>()` but you probably shouldn't be able to.

You were undoubtedly focused on extending a type by adding more properties to it, but were not paying attention to extending a type by narrowing the types of *existing* properties.

---

You *could* tighten the constraints on `A` and `B` to make it so that any keys shared by both `A` and `B` have mutually assignable property types, by specifying that `A extends B` and that `B extends Pick<A, keyof A & keyof B>`.  For any key `K` in `keyof A & keyof B`, `A extends B` implies `A[K] extends B[K]`, and `B extends Pick<A, keyof A & keyof B>` implies `B[K] extends A[K]`.

And inside the implementation, once you are absolutely convinced by your superior human reasoning skills that `Omit<A, keyof B> & B` is really the same thing as `A` (I hope), but the compiler is not convinced, you can lord your intelligence over the compiler by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

Let's see it in action:

```
// more strict constraint
const func = <A extends B, B extends Pick<A, keyof A & keyof B>>() => {
    const aWithoutB: Omit<A, keyof B> = {} as any;
    const b: B = {} as any;    
    const a = {
        ...aWithoutB,
        ...b
    } as A; // I'm smarter than the compiler 
};

func<Alpha, Beta>(); // error now, as desired
func<Beta & { extraProp: string }, Beta>(); // okay
```

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!