# Assign intersection of minuend and difference to intersection of subtrahend and minuend

Tags: typescript

I've borrowed the terms subtrahend, minuend and difference from [mathematical terminology for subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction#Notation_and_terminology).

I have two types, `Foo` and `Bar`, which should be simple objects with keys and values that may or may not have overlapping keys. I want a type `OnlyFoo` which is the difference between the subtrahend `Foo` and the minuend `Bar`. This is quite simple:

```
type OnlyFoo = Omit<Foo, keyof Bar>
```

Later I wish to assign the intersection `OnlyFoo & Bar` to `Foo & Bar`, but I can't find a way to do this without TypeScript giving errors.

Here is a more concrete code example. It's basically a factory for a function which takes an object of type `OnlyFoo` and returns a full `Foo & Bar` object.

```
const test = <Foo, Bar>(bar: Bar) => (
  fooOnly: Omit<Foo, keyof Bar>
) => {
  const fooBar: Foo & Bar = { ...fooOnly, ...bar };
};
```

TypeScript gives the following error for the `fooBar` assignment of that code:

```
// Type 'Pick<Foo, Exclude<keyof Foo, keyof Bar>> & Bar' is not assignable to type 'Foo & Bar'.
//   Type 'Pick<Foo, Exclude<keyof Foo, keyof Bar>> & Bar' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
//     'Pick<Foo, Exclude<keyof Foo, keyof Bar>> & Bar' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Foo', but 'Foo' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2322)
```

Here is the same example in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YB4BiIQBoYCEBDAJwD4AKAIxIC4CSBKFUmcgKBhgDNsB5MADYBPOrwC2ASyiZseANbwhILvTJsmyFgG8OMUJFg8QRYnSwgYAMlUoYWmADonR-sLxOH1YjAC+AbjZ-IA).

The error message suggests that "`Foo` could be instantiated with a subtype of constraint `{}`" that would make the assignment illegal. I can't seem to think any such type. Is there any further restriction I can make on `Foo` to make this possible?

Comment: could you link something from the typescript playground?

Comment: @Renaud I've updated the question to include a link to the same example in the TypeScript Playground

Comment: it seems to be an issue specifically to do with generics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyMmAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4GiSyIoBCcUOBYsgBGfCtVohGLAmACeABxSoArgC81yALzIA8gFtgYADwZ0AGmQBrCHPQxkvKAD4m+eUsfrNOp8gBkaN5uCOgg1CLeFNze2gKExKToFADkACZwlDAp5oLEolCplGnZMvgEoeFgyJAROgAUBdF8AJTazsj1eUm6IAA2chQGRqaYljZ2Dk7OBG1aHXgJlRFJThRmAY58cdjIAHQHPf1ylgd7BcjMbldAA

Comment: Yes, I believe this is because the compiler knows the exact type of `Foo`, so it's not possible for `Foo` to be "instantiated with a different subtype..."

Comment: seems related to these typescript issues: [28274](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28274), [28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) and [36316](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36316).
see also this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177506/a-extends-b-type-picka-excludekeyof-a-keyof-b-b-is-not-assignable-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is known limitation of TS that Omit,Exclude don't work well with generics. Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36316) and the response:

> We don't have any mechanisms available that could resolve this. The problem is that Exclude is a higher-order operation; when its input is generic, we don't have any way to predict what comes out the other side.

The only thing you can do is type assertion:

```
{ ...fooOnly as Foo, ...bar }
```

Comment: `{ ...fooOnly as Foo, ...bar }` is type casting, assertion with type guards would be safer at runtime.

Comment: @Renaud Could you give an example of how an assertion with a  type guard would look in this case?

Comment: You don't need type guard here.

Comment: here is an example [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAJYFM7wLzwDwDFzgDTwBCAhgE4B8AFAEbkBcx5AlOhfFcPPAGZ4DykADYBPRvwC2AS1g48hANZIR4Hk0rBWadgG8u8CDARToucOixUJJETSSMz8AD7wSkEVvbXbSeCfhm7FRWNnae8Hrc3AD00fAA7gAWJMgAbkhk8CoArgluCIkZSPrcZEiw2WSQiGTZSADc+gC+zPqGqHzgpGQOePAAZOoWkVEAdONUJmZUnYKirAD8vALCIvCMetEAVIiJ-jRkbqCJ8NCJ4NlCACbwkOAFJAAOj0jVNNkIAFbZqFLVoCRoL4cvBkulXNVwI9YFIoKCivAttESvAmq5oAE8MxCONRnQyM1Gk16kA)

Comment: @MaciejSikora my bad I didn't know about the correct terminology, [type assertion is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994926/detailed-differences-between-type-annotation-variable-type-and-type-assertion)